# Generated object array does not act the same as static test object array

Tags: angular, typescript, xlsx, angular8

I'm trying to generate an excel sheet with json data using 'xlsx'. Everything seems to work correctly when i use test data:

```
//outputs excel file correctly with data

var excelData = [{ test: 'test', test2: "yes" }, { test: 'testingAgain', test2: "no" }];
this.excelService.exportJSON(excelData, "test2");
```

but when i generate my own array of objects with dynamic properties it refuses to work, even though when i debug - the above static test object and the dynamic generated object look identical - my excel file outputs with zero data in it.

```
//outputs empty file even though object Array is a valid object containing valid data with object keys.

var objectArray = [];
dataDocs.forEach(doc => {
    let obj = {};
    obj["test"] = "test";
    obj["test2"] = "yes";
    objectArray.push(obj);
}
this.excelService.exportJSON(objectArray , "test3");
```

my excel service:

```
 export class ExcelService {

  private EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
  private EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

  constructor() { }

  exportJSON(jsonData: any, fileName) {
    let worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData);
    let workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    let excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });

    return this.generateExcelFile(excelBuffer, fileName);
  }
  private generateExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string) {
    let data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: this.EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    return FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + this.EXCEL_EXTENSION)
  }
}
```

[image: output in console to prove there is at least 1 object in object array]

I'd appreciate any help. Above is a snippet of what i'm trying to explain. The object array that is initialized with 2 objects and properties works fine in xls, but if i generate objects and push them to an object array it does not seem to work with xlsx (even though both of them are valid object arrays)\

(the top object array doesnt work, the bottom object array works)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `dataDocs` array is empty. So try to add check condition to see whether `dataDocs` contains data to run `foreach` statement:

```
var objectArray = [];
if (dataDocs && dataDocs.length > 0) {
    dataDocs.forEach(doc => {
        let obj = {};
        obj["test"] = "test";
        obj["test2"] = "yes";
        objectArray.push(obj);
    }
}
this.excelService.exportJSON(objectArray , "test3");
```

**UPDATE:**

You can add check condition to see whether `objectArray` contains data and if it has data then just call `exportJson` method:

```
if (objectArray && objectArray.length > 0) {
    this.excelService.exportJSON(objectArray , "test3");
}
```

Comment: I've updated my post with a snippet showing the two objects in console - and that there is at least 1 record in data docs.

Comment: @Steevy do you mean that `objectArray` has two items in array?

Comment: No I mean that objectArray's object properties are generated using bracket notation and then pushed to objectArray. This then doesn't seem to work with xlsx. but if I create objectArray with 2 test objects inside of it from initialization(never pushing to it)  it works in xlsx.

Comment: @Steevy are you sure that `exportJSON` method has values in `jsonData` when you call it with `objectArray `?

Comment: So my export json function wasn't receiving any data. I changed the .forEach to a normal for loop randomly and it works fine. I have zero clue as to why.

Comment: @Steevy it is really strange behavior. If there would be some [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example, then we can see what happens. However, it is normal to add items into `foreach` method. In addition add checking before `exportJSON` method is called. I've updated my reply.